# How to break a JSON response into smaller JSON part of a particular batch size

Tags: json, mule, mule-studio

I have a small issue ... I am exposing a REST service which fetch a list of data in JSON format..
The following is my flow :-

```
<flow name="MainService" doc:name="MainService">
 <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
 <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
 <component class="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.MainDataImpl"/>
</jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

Now If I hit the service I am getting the response in following format :-

```
{
   "retrieveAllData":
   [
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 1231,
           "name": "abc",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 165,
           "name": "test",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 134,
           "name": "test2",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 7,
           "name": "test3",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 9,
           "name": "testagain",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 10,
           "name": "newteat",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 11,
           "name": "ani",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 12,
           "name": "test",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 135,
           "name": "fff",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 166,
           "name": "fff",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 167,
           "name": "fff",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 444,
           "name": "fff",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 446,
           "name": "fff",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 447,
           "name": "fff",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 442,
           "name": "fff",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 133,
           "name": "fff",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 4,
           "name": "againtest",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 3,
           "name": "fdf",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 8,
           "name": "fff",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       },
       {
           "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
           "id": 445,
           "name": "fff",
           "age": 561,
           "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
       }
   ]
}
```

Now, Since this response is long and huge, I want to split this response in smaller part in a batch of 5 like :-

```
 {
               "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
               "id": 447,
               "name": "test",
               "age": 561,
               "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
           },
           {
               "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
               "id": 442,
               "name": "test2",
               "age": 561,
               "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
           },
           {
               "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
               "id": 133,
               "name": "fff",
               "age": 561,
               "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
           },
           {
               "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
               "id": 4,
               "name": "test3",
               "age": 561,
               "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
           },
           {
               "response": "The Data retrieved from the Database",
               "id": 3,
               "name": "fff",
               "age": 561,
               "designation": "Senior Software Engineer"
           }
```

So, I followed the following :-  [Mule - split a big JSON list into multiple smaller JSON lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189150/mule-split-a-big-json-list-into-multiple-smaller-json-lists?rq=1)

and after the jersey component in my flow I put the following :-

```
 <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map"/>
  <foreach batchSize="5">
  <json:object-to-json-transformer/>
   <logger message="ResponseLogdadasd :- #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="ResponseLogger"/>
</foreach>
```

Now, I am getting the following exception :-

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: ->org.mule.DefaultMuleContext["workManager"]->org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager["muleContext"]->org.mule.DefaultMuleContext["workManager"]->org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager["muleContext"]->org.mule.DefaultMuleContext["workManager"]->org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager["muleContext"]->org.mule.DefaultMuleContext["workManager"]->org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager["muleContext"]->org.mule.DefaultMuleContext["workManager"]->org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager["muleContext"]->org.mule.DefaultMuleContext["workManager"]->org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager["muleContext"]->org.mule.DefaultMuleContext["workManager"]->org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager["muleContext"]->org.mule.DefaultMuleContext["workManager"]->org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager["muleContext"]->org.mule.DefaultMuleContext["workManager"]->org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager["muleContext"]->org.mule.DefaultMuleContext["workManager"]->org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager["muleContext"]->org.mule.DefaultMuleContext["workManager"]->org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager["muleContext"]->org.mule.DefaultMuleContext["workManager"]->org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager["muleContex...--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Am I doing right ?? Is this the way will I can get to break the response into a smaller part in a batch size of 5 ?? Your suggestion please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the JSON from your question, the code

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map"/>
```

generates a map with one key "**retrieveAllData**" (which will contain the collection that you are looking for).

Try the following:

```
<foreach batchSize="5" collection="#[payload['retrieveAllData']]">
  <json:object-to-json-transformer/>
   <logger message="ResponseLogdadasd :- #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="ResponseLogger"/>
</foreach>
```

Comment: I am getting the same exception Nuno

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189150/mule-split-a-big-json-list-into-multiple-smaller-json-lists?rq=1) you mention, the payload has to be a collection. The class java.util.Map [is not a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651819/why-doesnt-java-map-extends-collection).